# [tag][Android/Gradle] Removing import statements from Android Library code for a particular flavor of the library using Gradle tasks

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Android library project which has two flavors let's say `libFlavor1` & `libFlavor2`. I have the same `core.java` file for both of them. `libFlavor2` requires extra code in the `core.java` file for additional features.

Currently my `core.java` has the entire code required for `libFlavor1` plus the extra code for `libFlavor2`. I wanted to know how we can remove the extra code to generate a build for the `libFlavor1` using **Gradle tasks**.

libFlavor2

```
import A
import B
import c
```

libFlavor1

```
import A
```

Code to removed includes some import statements and functions related 
 to `libFlavor2`.

How can we use Gradle tasks to modify the Java src files for particular library flavor?

Comment: I don't think a Gradle task is the appropriate solution to your problem. You should just use different source files for each of your flavors. They can both depend on a core feature set needed by both flavors.

Comment: @AutonomousApps Inn my case, it will be like maintaining two versions of very similar files. There are few imports and some initializations to be done for Flavor2.

Comment: I understand, but even so I think it would be very unusual for a Gradle task to directly modify a source file like that. Generating source files in `build/`, sure, but _modifying_ source files? If you're already using a dependency injection framework like dagger, you could also inject different implementation of the same interface depending on flavor.